# Dimension of image of linear transformation

Tags: linear-transformations

I am trying to understand this topic.

I am given this linear transformation $f: R^2 → R^3$ defined by:

$f(2,3) = (1,0,2), f(-1,2) = (-1,2,1)$

I am confused with the way $f$ is defined, I need to get the dimension of the image, I would usually use

$dimU = dimKernel + dimImage$

However, I cant get the kernel of $f$ since there are no vectors with their image as the null vector, right? so this leaves me with

$2 = 0 + x, x = 2$

But since I also need to get the associated matrix of $f$ for the canonical bases I am sure $f$ has a kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: write $f$ as a matrix. Then the dimension of the image is equal to the number of linearly independent rows.

Comment: Great. What about getting the associated matrix of f for the canonical bases? With the way F is defined I cant think of how to achieve this. any hint?

Comment: You know $f [2,3]^T$ and $[2,3]^T = 2[1,0]^T + 3[0,1]^{T}$ since $f$ is linear then $[1,0,2]^T = 2f[1,0]^T + 3f[0,1]^T$ and the same for the other point. The matrix elements can then be calculated by $f_{11} = [1,0,0]f[1,0]^T$ and so on.